# C# opensource djvu library

Tags: c#, djvu

Do you know any opensource libraries for DJVU? I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most rated DjVU library is here:

[DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/)

However is in C++.

Answer (score 4):

I created an open source Djvu library which is written in C#. It needs to be optimized a bit, but is fully usable. https://github.com/Telavian/DjvuNet

Answer (score 2):

As for open source [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) mentioned by Steve, you could find some pointers how to use it from .NET here - [Creating simple c++.net wrapper. Step-by-step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637571/creating-simple-c-net-wrapper-step-by-step)

As for paid libraries - you could look at: [Caminova DjVu SDK for .NET Framework](http://dev.caminova.jp/djvusharp/). This is not too expensive.

Comment: C++ is good, but not for WP7 :)