# How to use foobar SDK to play music in my C# application

Tags: c#, audio

I tried using audio libraries like NAudio, Bass and others. But couldn't get them to play all audio format on lower configuration machines. As i am already a huge fan of foobar, so i would like to use foobar library in my application. But i couldn't figure out a way to do so. I went through the Foobar SDK but was unable to understand where to start from. SO if you guys can provide some basic guidance or way to help me understand implementing foobar libraries to play audio in my C# application i would be very grateful.

Actually we were using NAudio library to play audio. All was working fine but it failed to play some audio formats in lower end machines like Windows 2003 server. So i was seeking refuge with greatest audio player ever made, Foobar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The foobar SDK is meant to be used with lower level languages (c++/c) and not .net languages. To be able to use it with c# you'd have to write a wrapper to manage the c++ code (see: [Creating simple c++.net wrapper. Step-by-step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637571/creating-simple-c-net-wrapper-step-by-step) how to do so). Altough, you have to consider this is very time consuming and I'd recommend either learning c++ to use the SDK natively or use another library to perform the same task.