# Mono application recording desktop/running application into movie

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform

I have to create screen/current application recording tool into movie working on Windows and MacOS. I'm going to use Mono and I found a PAID library [ByteScout](https://bytescout.com/) for it.

I'm wondering if there is any FREE library for Mono doing the recording of screen/running application?

Any OTHER suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) as it is cross-platform by nature.

It may not be the right fit licensing wise, so pay attention to this front.

As far as the Official development, C# is not the language of choice used to develop OBS, but there are others out there who have made some headway on this front.

I would recommend [GoaLitiuM's C# wrapper re-write "libobs-sharp"](https://github.com/GoaLitiuM/libobs-sharp) as a starting point, as Mono is a part of this user's goals in the effort.

---

**Appended Information**

---

If you are not happy with the progress of the open source community's efforts, you can always download the OBS source yourself, and begin to make your own wrapper(s) as well.

[This article may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637571/creating-simple-c-net-wrapper-step-by-step)

Comment: It seems to be  a finished program, not a framework or development solution. So probably I cannot modify/customize appearance/how it looks, right?

Comment: @P.K. after looking at the ["Official Getting Started Dev Docs -> Read the documentation"](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/getting-started-with-obs-development.21326/) it seems as if this is only the core functionality portion, and that UI would be completely separate.